# Unable to compile java file containing apache camel program

Tags: compiler-errors, apache-camel, javac, camel-core

I am a beginner at using Apache Camel. I have a maven project with the following structure:

[image]

File Write_Paper contains the content below:

[image]

When I compile this file by using cmd with: `javac Write_Paper.java`, I get some errors:

```
Write_Paper.java:3: error: package org.apache.camel does not exist
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;

Write_Paper.java:4: error: package org.apache.camel.builder does not exist
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

Write_Paper.java:5: error: package org.apache.camel.impl does not exist
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

Write_Paper.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext()

  symbol:   class CamelContext
  location: class Write_Paper
Write_Paper.java:9: error: cannot find symbol

  symbol:   class DefaultCamelContext
  location: class Write_Paper
Write_Paper.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

  symbol:   class RouteBuilder
  location: class Write_Paper
Write_Paper.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
                from("file:sourceFolder?noop=true")

  symbol: method from(String)

7 errors
```

`pom.xml` file content here

[image]

I have tried many solutions but I cannot fix them. what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Standalone java code

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
    
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("file:source?noop=true").to("file:dest");
            }
        });
        context.close();
        context.start();
    }
}
```

keep the file inside the **src/main/resources** folder:

file name = **log4j.properties**
inside file content:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %L - %m%n
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but I still can't fix these errors even though I changed camel version to 3.20.2 as you suggested. I am using java 11, maven 3.9.0, Do you have any other solution?

Comment: above code is updated acording to you, check and let me know it's working or not.

Comment: the file above log4j is automatically generated or do i have to create it? I have rebuilt mvn but can't find it. so i created this file manually.
These errors still appear when I compile with cmd : javac Write_Paper.java